# Como faço para imprimir uma matriz em forma de linhas e colunas?

Tags: c, array, matriz

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int m[3][2];

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
            printf("Digite o elemento na linha e coluna [%d],[%d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &m[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("a matriz e:\n");
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
            printf("%d", m[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ja tentou um printf("\n") no for mais externo?

Comment: @BernardoLopes consegui aqui vlw!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
  for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
    printf("%d", m[i][j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

apenas insira um "printf("\n");" entre os dois laços for para que exista uma quebra de linha entre as linhas da matriz